# Branch made by several custom values

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

Below code from function.php works fine when the custom value used for conditional branch is only one.

This code means if custom key A is AAA, update custom key B as ZZZ.

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_A',true) == AAA) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_B', 'ZZZ ');
}
```

I like to add many custom values into this code.
Like, if custom key A is AAA or BBB or CCC or DDD, update key B as ZZZ.

I tried like this, but it failed.

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_A',true) == 'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD') {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_B', 'ZZZ ');
}
```

Is it possible to make it ?

Comment: so you wanted: "if A == B or  A == C or  A == D", and tried: "if A == B, C, D" but it didn't work? Have you tried   "if A == B or A == C or A == D"? This isn't a WordPress question, this looks like a PHP question about if statements and comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), like this:

```
$search = [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD' ];
$meta   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_A', true );

if ( in_array( $meta, $search ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MY_CUSTOM_KEY_B', 'ZZZ' );
}
```

Comment: Hi fuxia  Thank you so much for your beautiful code.  It works exactly as I expected.  I changed "$post->" to "$post->ID".